# Why is the humanitarian crisis in Israel seen as an opportunity to violate the human rights of certain groups in certain countries?

Tags: international-law, human-rights

> **With the world’s attention focused on the carnage in Israel and Gaza,
> there is an urgent need to protect civilians at risk of further forced
> displacement or mass expulsion. Unfortunately, others are seeing an
> opportunity to take or escalate drastic measures such as mass refugee
> expulsions against unwanted groups in their own countries.**
>
> The risk to longstanding refugee populations in protracted exile looks
> especially dire. The warning signs are clear in four places, though
> this by no means is an exhaustive list.
>
> First, in Pakistan, the Interior Ministry announced on Oct. 3 that all
> unregistered Afghans, including many who have lived there for years,
> had to leave the country by Nov. 1. Broad calls by Pakistani officials
> for mass deportation coincided with an increase in harassment,
> assault, and arbitrary detention of Afghans. The deadline for
> “voluntary” return having passed last week, Pakistani police are now
> going house to house, rounding up Afghans and beginning to deport them
> in the thousands.

https://thehill.com/opinion/international/4302089-as-gaza-burns-other-countries-are-quietly-illegally-dumping-refugees/

Why is the humanitarian crisis in Israel seen as an opportunity to violate the human rights of certain groups?

The article suggests that because attention is diverted towards Israel, committing human right violations might carry less risk, but is this really the case? What are the flaws in the system in international justice that allows this to be seen as an opportunity?

Comment: a political manipulations: to do dirty things under covering of tragedy others. Emotional narratives is making distress to common people and leading their reasoning look aside, away from pain. Easiest technic of illusionist.

Comment: *announced on Oct. 3* is hardly a good example for this Q.  Plus, Pakistan-Afghan relations have been sketchy for a while so the relation to 10/7+Gaza is even more tenuous.  How could this Q possibly be answered without a lot of opinion and speculation?  Esp when it applies to multiple countries, with governments which certainly wont trumpet their motivations for those alleged abuses,

Comment: Political ideas become more acceptable when they are publicised - western media has given quite a lot of space to Israel's idea of displacing refugees and making them somebody else's responsibility. Moreover, if someone acts on this idea, it creates an international precedent that others can cite too.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/And_you_are_lynching_Negroes

Comment: You are citing an opinion piece that claims, without evidence, that deportations of Afghans from Pakistan is related to the carnage in Gaza. While writers often try to find such connections, bottom line is that it is baseless speculation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Indeed, some notorious human rights abusers are given opportunity to embellish their reputation by their self-righteous stand on the Israel-Gaza issue. Some of them also make use of the fact that the world attention is focused on Gaza, to carry out military action against their opponents.

E.g., [this article by Tahrir Institute for Middle East policy](https://timep.org/2024/02/06/smoke-and-mirrors-assads-exploitation-of-israels-war-on-gaza-to-escalate-atrocities-in-idlib/) describes how Bashar Assad of Syria is using this opportunity to achieve his objectives in Idlib:

> Over the past four months, the world’s attention has rightfully been centered on Gaza, drawn by the distressing realities unfolding on the ground. The toll on civilian lives, severe blockades, scarcity of essential supplies, and the relentless targeting of civilian infrastructure, residential zones, and camps underscore the gravity of the situation. Capitalizing on the world’s singular focus on Gaza, war criminals like Bashar al-Assad are exploiting the situation as a smokescreen to advance their own agendas. **Indeed, the Syrian regime has strategically intensified its assaults on civilians in Idlib since October to perpetuate violence with minimal attention.** These attacks, compounded by the unforgiving winter and the somber first anniversary of the region’s catastrophic earthquake, have deepened the anguish for residents, layering misery upon misery.
>
> Between October and mid-November 2023, regime and Russian forces executed 570 attacks, resulting in the deaths of 114 civilians. This calculated exploitation extends beyond the battlefield. **Assad is strategically denouncing Israel’s actions not out of moral objection but as a means to assume a false moral high ground and cleanse his tarnished reputation.**

Indeed, [Idlib has already been characterized as a "second Gaza" in the past](https://www.washingtoninstitute.org/policy-analysis/idlib-may-become-next-gaza-strip) (i.e., prior to October 7 attacks):

> Russia and Turkey’s March 5 ceasefire agreement in Syria’s Idlib province was the latest step in a process that has shrunk the rebel pocket in half since April 2019. Yet even this arrangement is only temporary given Bashar al-Assad’s determination to do away with what he and his allies see as “Jihadistan.” A closer look at the area’s territorial and demographic situation shows how ongoing developments will likely lead to the creation of **a “New Gaza Strip” in northwest Syria—that is, an overpopulated refugee zone where terrorists are in control, essentially forcing the international community to work with them because they are the “de facto authorities,” as the UN puts it.**